# Doxygen: Generate different content based on certain switch

Tags: doxygen

My code has a compiler switch to support different platforms. I would like to use doxygen to generate different content based on this compiler switch.

```
#define UsedPlatform PlatformA
```

Is there anything like #if(UsedPlatform==PlatformA) that I can use in .dox file to generate different html content?

Example of .dox file

```
/**
 * \page chapter3 Chapter 3: Internal Design

 \tableofcontents

\section c3_static_view 3.1 Static View

Contents

Example:
#if(UsedPlatform==PlatformA)
It is using Platform A
#else
It is using Platform B
#endif

*/
```

Comment: which version of doxygen are you using?  Can you give a small (full) example? Doxygen does understand `#if` directives etc as well,. You could also look at the doxygen commands like `\cond` and \if`)

Comment: Thanks for your hint! I can define ENABLED_SECTIONS and use \if to generate different content. But it will be better if i can use `#if(UsedPlatform==PlatformA)` in the .dox file

Comment: What is your `dox` file? a documentation file, a configuration file, a... file? Small example please.

Comment: Sorry, it is a documentation file. I added an example

Answer (score 0):

Doxygen does not recognize the `#if` constructs in the comments, neither would a compiler. The later can be illustrated by  by means of e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
/**
#if 0
*/

void fie()
{
  printf("Hello world\n");
}

/**
#endif
*/


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  fie();
  return 0;
}
```

this compiles, links and runs without problems.

So one has the use (in this case) `\if` commands (or for parts spanning multiple comment blocks `\cond`).